# Как создать динамический массив C?

Tags: массивы, c

Необходимо прочитать из файла число *N*, создать массив *NxN* и полностью инициализировать его 1-ми. Вот как я делаю это на **C++**:

```
int **Graf, i, j, N;
 ifstream input("Graf.txt");
 input >> N;

 Graf = new int *[N];
 for(i=0; i<N; i++)
     Graf[i] = new int[N];

 //Обнуляет все элементы массива
 for(i=0; i<N; i++)
     for(j=0; j<N; j++)
         Graf[i][j]=0;
 while(!input.eof())
 {
     input>>i>>j;
     Graf[i][j]=1;
     Graf[j][i]=1;
 }
```

Как это перевести на **C**?

Comment: @derkode а можно узнать для каких целей для работы с файлами Вы используете чистый Си?

Comment: Не знаю может это звучит глупо!) Но мне это нужно для Objective-C. Я в Xcode делаю консольное приложение для Mac OS. Что-то родного для двумерного массива в Objective-C я не нашел и решил использовать C, т.к. Objective-C его полностью поддерживает.

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт в Objective-C но по моему там существует NSArray. И еще:

arrayWithArray:
Creates and returns an array containing the objects in another given array.

+ (instancetype)arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray
Parameters
anArray
An array.
Return Value
An array containing the objects in anArray.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.0 and later.

Comment: Цикл с предусловием `!eof` - практически всегда ошибка и в С, и в С++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Graf = new int *[N];
```

Заменить на

```
Graf = (int**) malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
```

а

```
Graf[i] = new int[N];
```

Заменить на

```
Graf = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

Освобождение памяти для такой матрицы будет выглядеть так

```
for(i = 0;i < N;++i) free(Graf[i]);
free(Graf);
```

Ну и плюс ко всему нужно подключить stdlib.h

Comment: Ругается на строку "Graf = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));" cообщением: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int **'from 'int *'

Comment: @derkode, видимо звездочек в приведении типа (cast operation) не хватает. Надо точно так, как @Че Гевара написал.

    int **Graf = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*));

А еще, открою Вам страшную тайну, такая конструкция на самом деле не является двумерным массивом (не все ее элементы лежат в памяти подряд), хотя для операций доступа по индексам она выглядит хорошо.

Настоящий динамический двумерный массив с индексацией типа a[i][j] в Си сделать нельзя. Обычно все такие матрицы просто моделируют одномерными массивами 

    int *matr = (int *)malloc((M * N) * sizeof(int));
    matr[i*N + j] = 1;

Answer (score 2):

Выстраивать тут jagged array, как вы сделали в своем С++ коде, нет никакой необходимости. В языке С такой массив можно организовать существенно проще. Прочитав предварительно величину `N` просто делаем

```
int (*Graf)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof(int [N]));
```

Все.

После чего с полученным массивом можно работать как обычно

```
Graf[i][j] = 42;
```

Освобождение памяти делается единственным вызвом `free`

```
free(Graf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобятся ссылки и функции типа `malloc()`. Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536153/c-dynamically-growing-array) базовых операций на одномерном массиве (автор [casablanca @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381345/casablanca)):

```
typedef struct {
  int *array;
  size_t used;
  size_t size;
} Array;

void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
  a->array = (int *)malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
  a->used = 0;
  a->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Array *a, int element) {
  if (a->used == a->size) {
    a->size *= 2;
    a->array = (int *)realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
  }
  a->array[a->used++] = element;
}

void freeArray(Array *a) {
  free(a->array);
  a->array = NULL;
  a->used = a->size = 0;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
Array a;
int i;

initArray(&a, 5);  // initially 5 elements
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  insertArray(&a, i);  // automatically resizes as necessary
printf("%d\n", a.array[9]);  // print 10th element
printf("%d\n", a.used);  // print number of elements
freeArray(&a);
```

Двумерный массив может быть реализован как `**int`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку cdcontainers. Она написана на C, а интрфейс напоминает интрефейс стандартной библиотеки C++

https://github.com/maksimandrianov/cdcontainers

```
#define CDC_USE_SHORT_NAMES  // for short names (functions and structs without prefix cdc_*)
#include <cdcontainers/vector.h>
#include <cdcontainers/casts.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector_t *v;
    size_t i;

    if (vector_ctor(&v, NULL) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(7)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(8)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    for (i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i)
        printf("%i ", CDC_PTR_TO_INT(vector_get(v, i)));

    printf("\n");

    vector_dtor(v);

    return 0;
}
```