# динамический массив указателей

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

возник такой вопрос:
мне необходимо создать массив строк, и я решил реализовать его с помощью массива указателей.

```
char **strArr;
```

проблема в том, что кол-во самих строк = количество элементов данного массива я узнаю только после работы определённой функции. К примеру, пусть количество содержится в переменной `count`. Тогда:

```
func(&count); // функция, которая возвратит мне значение count
strArr = new char *[count];
```

и вот тут при компиляции программы компилятор начинает ругаться, мол, необъявленный идентификатор. Подскажите, что я не так делаю? Либо, если мой подход очень не рациональный, подскажите пример другой структуры, с помощью которой я мог реализовать хранение строк.

Comment: Принципиально, чтобы это был не C++? Там есть векторы.

Comment: к сожалению, да, принципиально.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/266399/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-c

Comment: Как бы, вы присваете pointer-pointer'y pointer (указателю на указатель, указатель), вот он и ругается.

Comment: Справедливо. Не судите строго: я новичок в си :) Спасибо большое за ссылку и за разъяснение !

Comment: До того, как спрашивать, гуглите вопрос, часто он отвечен много раз.

Comment: `new` - это не си.

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительно так (писал тут и не проверял):

```
char **allocate_strs(size_t n, size_t len) {
  char **res;
  size_t q;

  if (!(res = malloc(n * sizeof (char*))))
    return 0;

  for (q=0; q<n; ++q)
    if (!(res[q] = malloc(len)))
    {
      while (q--) free(res[q]);
      free(res);
      return 0;
    }

  return res;
}
```